# Return all id's from table in store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm continue discovering `SQL` and store procedure, having trouble that `@feedid` is returning only 1 id, but it have for ex. 20. How to return array of id's?

```
CREATE PROC spGetItemsByUser
    @userName NVARCHAR(50)
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @userId INT,
            @feedId INT;

    SELECT @userId = ID
    FROM users
    WHERE name = @userName

    SELECT @feedId = feedid
    FROM userstofeed
    WHERE userid = @userId

    SELECT *
    FROM feed
    WHERE ID = @feedId

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use *table* variables:

```
declare @userId table (uid int)
declare @feedId table (id int)

insert into @userid(uid)
select id 
from Users 
where name = @userName

insert into @feedid(id)
select feedid 
from userstofeed 
where userid in (select uid from @userId)

select * from feed where id in (select id from @feedId)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or just go by simple and plain join

```
create proc spGetItemsByUser
    @userName nvarchar(50)
as
begin

    select * from Users usr
    join UsersToFeed utf on usr.id = utf.userID
    join feed fee on utf.feedid = fee.id
    where usr.name = @userName
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROC spGetItemsByUser
(
    @userName NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @userId INT

    SELECT @userId = ID
    FROM users
    WHERE name = @userName

    SELECT *
    FROM feed f
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM userstofeed uf
        WHERE f.ID = uf.feedid
            AND uf.userid = @userId
    ) 

END
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to do this in steps. Your variables are only going to ever hold a single variable at any given time, even if you set it in a `SELECT` query that has multiple results. Just put this all into one query and you should be fine:

```
SELECT
    F.feed_id,
    F.other_columns    -- NEVER use SELECT *
FROM
    Users U
INNER JOIN UsersToFeed UTF ON UTF.userid = U.userid
INNER JOIN Feed F ON F.feedid = UTF.feedid
WHERE
    U.UserName = @UserName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROC spGetItemsByUser
    @userName NVARCHAR(50)
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @userId INT,
            @feedId INT;

    SELECT @userId = ID
    FROM users
    WHERE name = @userName

    SELECT *
    FROM feed
    WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT feedid
        FROM userstofeed
        WHERE userid = @userId
    )

END
```